# D3JS Map Citiy Circles

Tags: json, database, d3.js, colors, geometry

I'm currently creating a map of germany with d3js to visualize some data. I now added some Cities by using a csv, which are shown as circles in the map. I want some cities to have a different color the more data are used in them. Does anybody have a idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a range of color like this:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([d3.min(array), d3.max(array)])
                      .range(["#fff7f3", "#49006a"]);
```

then style every circle:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
                        return color(+d.data);
                  });
```

But you need to compact your data to just one value per city like so:

```
d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){
            return sum + d.amount;
        },0)
```

Here's an example from Mike's Site: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606